# how i can change JS variable from Code behinde c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how i can change value for (min, max, values[]) from c# code behinde?

thank you

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 60,
        max: 2000,
        values: [70, 999],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, you may need to provide more context for the users to understand your problem a bit better.
Could you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: `min: <%= variable %>`

Comment: Thank you very much this work fine : min: <%= variable %>